# Set theory - Axiom of Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Reading  Comprehensive Mathematics for Computer Scientists 1 chapter 2:

```
Axiom 3 (Axiom of Union) If a is a set, then there is a set:

{x | there exists an element b∈a such that x∈b}.

This set is denoted by ⋃a and is called the union of a.

Notation 2 If a = {b,c}. or a = {b,c,d}, respectively, one also writes b ∪ c, or b ∪ c ∪ d, respectively, instead of ∪a
```

What if a = {1,2} then b = 1 how can x belong to b if it's not a set?

Sorry I am a little confused...

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your example, $\cup a$ would be the empty set, because there is no $x$ satisfying the definition. For a more interesting example, consider $a = \{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$.

Comment: Okay thanks, so in your example Ua = {1,2}?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Bungo, you might want to be a bit careful. For instance, the natural number $n$ is often defined to be the set $\{0,...,n-1\}$, in which case what you are saying is not true. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in frameworks where the axiom of union appears (e.g. ZFC), *everything is a set !*

For instance, the natural numbers are usually defined to be $0:=\{\}$ and recursively by $n+1 := n\cup \{n\}$. More informally, we have $n= \{0,..., n-1\}$.

So for instance, in your example

$$\bigcup \{1,2\} = \bigcup \{\{0\}, \{0,1\}\} = \{0,1\}$$

more generally it is easy to see that if $A$ is a finite set consisting only of natural numbers (with the above definition), then $\bigcup A = \max A$.